# Why doesn't Gdaladdo make the background transparent?

Tags: gdal

I noticed that the backgrounds of my geotiffs were transparent up until I started added overviews with gdaladdo.

Is there a way to combat this?`

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue. As far as I can tell it's not related to gdal not honoring the nodata but to the fact that the jpeg compression I'm using truncates my 16bit geotiffs to 12bit in the overviews.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to raise a bug on the gdal-dev mailing list, because the [page](http://www.gdal.org/gdaladdo.html) for `gdaladdo` says that it "will honour properly NODATA_VALUES tuples".

Although I've just thought, is your data using a mask band rather than a nodata value? That might be the issue because the formats that are used for overviews may not support a mask band - although that is mostly speculation.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, this was a bug in gdaladdo that has been fixed, refer to 
https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6836

If you use GDAL 2.2.3, you will no longer have this issue.